How to Access Multiple MinIO (S3) Endpoints Simultaneously Using Trino?
I'm currently using Trino SQL to read and join files from different MinIO endpoints. However, I'm facing an issue with the following setup (all installed using Docker):

Trino: version 447

Configured minio1.properties and minio2.properties, both using the same Hive Metastore.


Hive Metastore: version 3.3.1 (using PostgreSQL)

hive-site.xml is configured to connect to MinIO1.
MinIO1 is set up to avoid access-key issues when trying to read MinIO data using Trino SQL.


MinIO: 2 containers

MinIO1 contains bucket1 with file /bucket1/data/a.csv.
MinIO2 contains bucket2 with file /bucket2/data/b.csv.



hive-site.xml for HiveMetastore
<configuration>
  ...
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value><access-key-1></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value><secret-key-1></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
    <value>http://minio-1:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

</configuration>

Trino Catalogs
# minio1.properties
connector.name=hive
fs.native-s3.enabled=true
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hive-metastore:9083
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled=true
s3.aws-access-key=<access-key-1>
s3.aws-secret-key=<secret-key-1>
s3.endpoint=http://minio-1:9000
s3.max-connections=3
s3.path-style-access=true
s3.region=default
s3.streaming.part-size=32MB
s3.tcp-keep-alive=false

# minio2.properties
connector.name=hive
fs.native-s3.enabled=true
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hive-metastore:9083
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled=true
s3.aws-access-key=<access-key-2>
s3.aws-secret-key=<secret-key-2>
s3.endpoint=http://minio-2:9000
s3.max-connections=3
s3.path-style-access=true
s3.region=default
s3.streaming.part-size=32MB
s3.tcp-keep-alive=false

Trino SQL:
CREATE TABLE minio1.default.data1 (
  a VARCHAR,
  b VARCHAR
) WITH (
  format = 'CSV',
  external_location = 's3a://bucket1/data/a.csv'
);

CREATE TABLE minio2.default.data2 (
  a VARCHAR,
  b VARCHAR
) WITH (
  format = 'CSV',
  external_location = 's3a://bucket2/data/b.csv'
);

Issue:
The first SQL query executes successfully, but the second one fails with the following error:
Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.UnknownStoreException `s3a://bucket2/data/b.csv': 
  getFileStatus on s3a://bucket2/data/b.csv: 
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
      The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: aaa; S3 Extended Request ID: 711af550-b344-4a8e-a564-c7362c2ff38b; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 711af550-b344-4a8e-a564-c7362c2ff38b:NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: 17D8C3C418303754; S3 Extended Request ID: 711af550-b344-4a8e-a564-c7362c2ff38b; Proxy: null)

The reason for the error seems to be that it attempts to read the same path (/bucket2/data/b.csv) to minio1 without reading the data from minio2(hive-site.xml setting in hive-metastore is set to minio1). However, I definitely used minio2 catalog of trino.
Question:
Why is this happening, and how can I correctly configure Trino and Hive Metastore to access and join data from multiple MinIO endpoints?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I would start by searching for "troubleshooting s3a" docs and go from there. it is a configuration problem, not a code one
